# If then jquery statement to show and hide given certain conditions

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Im using the following jquery script to prioritize leads/order records on a table on a CRM:

```
$('#SubscribersManageList tr:not("tr.Heading3"):contains("**-********"):not(:contains("$")):not(:contains("Ahora")):not(:contains("tel:")):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");

$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("No quiero contratar"):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");

$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("No lo sé"):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");

$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("En 15"):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').css("background-color", "#FE8").insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");

$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("En 7"):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').css("background-color", "#FE8").insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");

$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("tel:"):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').css({'background-color' : '#F9B820', 'font-size' : '12px'}).insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");

$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("Ahora"):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').css({'background-color' : '#F9B820', 'font-size' : '12px'}).insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");

$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("Ahora"):contains("tel:"):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').css({'background-color' : '#F9B820', 'font-size' : '12px'}).insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");

$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("$"):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').css({'background-color' : '#F9B820', 'font-size' : '12px'}).insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");

$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("Ahora"):contains("tel:"):contains("$"):not(:has(img[src*="images/plus.gif"]))').css({'background-color' : '#F9B820', 'font-size' : '12px'}).insertAfter("tr.Heading3:last");
```

What I want to express and add to my code but cant do is:

I want to show only the records for the last 5 conditions and hide everything else until there are no records that match these last 5 conditions, then show the rest.

The last 5 conditions prioritize and assign a particular css-background to them, so what I want to do is that when NO other has the conditions expressed in the last 5 lines, then show the rest of the contacts.

Any help?

Comment: This is very confusing. Can you add something else to clarify?

Comment: So you have some data (in a table?) that you'd like to Show according to certain conditions? Where does the data originate from? Can't you filter it based on your conditions before you render it as a table? It all seems a bit convoluted to me.